# PHP Composer Laravel Installation Fatal Error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Can someone help me with resolving this error ? 
I have tried the options available across GIT and Stackoverflow but nothing works for me as of now.
I am trying to install larvel but always get stuck on this step.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
Changed current directory to /Users/Jay/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

Did someone encountered the same problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after looking into different options,
This one worked for me.

```
sudo composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, I wasn't entirely clear about your process but guessed that you ran this command, then re-ran the laravel install command, which works for me too - you might want to accept your own answer since it did solve the issue.